# iPhone 6s won't update any software

Tags: software-update

Every time new software is released by Apple for my iPhone 6s, I go to *Settings* to see the latest version that needs to be updated, but as soon as I click on *Update*, it closes out the *Settings App.* I have done a hard reset but nothing works. Can someone give me some advice on what could be causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: If that happens each time, and you've restarted your iPhone, you could try a network reset. If that doesn't work you're probably looking at reinstalling iOS on the iPhone.

Comment: Can you try upgrading while physically connected via USB?

Comment: As Jim Garrison points out, try connecting your iPhone to a Mac, then open up iTunes, go to your device, and hit upgrade software. That should help you out.